# Is "vector iterator + offset out of range" assertion useful at all?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, visual-studio-debugging

This perfectly good program fails in debug mode in Visual Studio 2013:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
  vector<int> v = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3};

  for (auto iFrom = v.cbegin(), iTo = iFrom+5; iFrom != v.cend(); iFrom = iTo, iTo += 5)
    cout << *max_element(iFrom, iTo) << '\n';
}
```

with `vector iterator + offset out of range` assertion failure. It fails because `iTo > v.cend()`, which is harmless here. What is the point of debugger testing the value of iterator, which is not being dereferenced?

BTW, I know that I can rewrite the loop above as:

```
for (auto i = v.cbegin(); i != v.cend(); i += 5)
  cout << *max_element(i, i+5) << '\n';
```

but I was trying to make a simple example out of a piece of more complex real-life code, where calculating the new iterator value is computationally expensive.

I also realize that one can change `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` value to affect this behavior, but it creates problems with binary versions of some libraries, which are built with default debug settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not harmless... it's *undefined behaviour* to attempt to move the iterator past `end()`, which you do on your third and final iteration.  The fact that immediately after doing so with `iTo += 5` you terminate your loop as `iFrom != v.cend()` without dereferencing the iterator is not relevant.

If efficiency is really necessary and you're prepared the bet the bank on the number of elements being a multiple of 5:

```
for (auto iFrom = v.cbegin(), iTo = iFrom; iFrom != v.cend(); iFrom = iTo)
{
    iTo += 5;
    cout << *max_element(iFrom, iTo) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: BTW, I'm prepared to bet the whole banking system on _the number of elements being a multiple of 5_ - the number is 10, which obviously is a multiple of 5 ;-)

Comment: @PaulJurczak: I didn't mean in your hard-coded sample vector, but in whatever real-world code you've simplified the posted code down from - where it may or may not be hard-coded. ;-P  Anyway, even though I work in the industry I'd happily bet the whole banking system on there being a rainbow and 3 shooting stars visible from Tokyo SkyTree at exactly 2am tomorrow, so I'm not sure what to make of your bet...!

Comment: I'm novice.I'm trying to add a element in 'v',when run it crash. Can you tell ?

Comment: @Chuanhang.gu: you haven't provided enough information to tell.  You should read about how to post your own question with minimal sample code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TonyD What I said is base on above example, the only modify is add one element in 'v',making code like bellow:     void main()
{
 vector<int> v = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3,-1 };

 for (auto iFrom = v.cbegin(), iTo = iFrom; iFrom != v.cend(); iFrom = iTo)
 {
  iTo += 5;
  cout << *max_element(iFrom, iTo) << '\n';
 }
}      .Recently I meet a strange question. If you can,please help answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681922/vectorreserve-cause-vector-iterator-offset-out-of-range

Comment: @Chuanhang.gu Your code above has undefined behaviour, as your vector has 11 elements which is not a multiple of 5.  As I say in my answer, you've "bet the bank" and lost the bet.  If you remove the "-1" it will start working.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure what the question is here, but the "point" is that VS is trying to aid in removing dangerous code. Yes, in principle a *pointer* could point anywhere if you didn't dereference it, but iterators are a higher level abstraction and have the ability to detect whether dereference would be valid and thus raise runtime errors. VS has done this with `vector<T>::iterator` at least since VS 2007.

Comment: My point is that _ability to detect whether dereference would be valid_ is very nice and useful, but why not do it only when the iterator **is** actually dereferenced, not before, when it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

max_element() takes two iterators and goes over the entire range between them.  If you think about it, the range isn't really valid if either of the iterators are invalid.  Both [SGI](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/max_element.html) and [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhk9z544.aspx) mention this as a prerequisite in their respective documentation:

SGI:

> Preconditions
>
> - [first, last) is a valid range.

MSDN:

> Remarks
>
> - The range referenced must be valid; all pointers must be dereferenceable and within each sequence the last position is
>     reachable from the first by incrementation.

If I were in your situation, I'd just add a check to see if iTo was still valid as the first step in my loop.  If it's not, set it to the last position in v.

Comment: That is true, but I never call `max_element()` with invalid range. The problem is in incrementing an iterator past `end()`.